# Basis for linearly dependent vectors in R3

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a subspace S where $(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and for $a, b, c\in R$, not all equal to zero, we have
$ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3 = 0$. What would be the basis for this subspace?

I tend to think that the basis would be less than 3 vectors, because I believe that S should have a dimension of less than 3 due to the linear dependence. But I can't think of how to find 2 vectors that would fulfill this requirement.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Dave I tend to think that the basis would be less than 3 vectors, because I believe that S should have a dimension of less than 3 due to the linear dependence. But I can't think of how to find 2 vectors that would fulfill this requirement

Comment: That's a good start. Think about the conditions on the coefficients $a,b,c$ and can you use these conditions to write one of the coordinates in terms of the others.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not enough information to answer this.  With what we have, it is possible that $x_1, x_2,x_3$ are all scalar multiples of one another.  So, any one of the 3 will serve as our basis.  Otherwise this is a 2 dimensional space and we will need 2 basis vectors.  Any two will do, so long as the two we choose are not scalar multiples of one another.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG we can assume that $a \ne 0.$ Then we have

$x_1= - \frac{b}{a}x_2- \frac{c}{a}x_3,$

$x_2=x_2$,

$x_3=x_3.$

With $t=x_2$ and $s= x_3$ we derive

$$(x_1,x_2,x_3)=t(- \frac{b}{a},1,0)+s(- \frac{c}{a},0,1).$$

This is an equation of a plane. A basis is given by

$$ \{(-b,a,0),(-c,0,a)\}.$$

Comment: I understand how you can define x1 in terms of the other two, but how did you get the equation of the plane?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this from a geometrical perspective, you basically have

$$(a,b,c) \cdot (x_1, x_2, x_3) = 0$$

This basically is describing a plane of vectors which is normal to the given vector $(a,b,c)$ - hence the basis would be any two non parallel vectors in this plane